# c program in files using fprintf and fscanf goes into infinite loop and prints only the last entry

Tags: c, file, loops, infinite

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
     clrscr();

     FILE *fp;
     int rno,m;
     char name[20];
     char ch;
     printf("INPUT DATA:\n");
     fp=fopen("DATA.txt","w");
     if(fp==NULL)
     {    
         printf("\nCan't open file or file doesn't exist");
         exit(0);
     }

     do
     {
         printf("\nEnter Roll number:");
         scanf("%d",&rno);
         fprintf(fp,"Roll number=%d",rno);
         printf("\nEnter name:");
         scanf("%s",name);
         fprintf(fp,"Name=%s",name);
         printf("\nEnter mark secured:");
         scanf("%d",&m);
         fprintf(fp,"Mark=%d",m);
         fprintf(fp,"%d %s %d",rno,name,m);
         printf("\nDo you want to add another data(Y/N):");
         ch=getche();
     }while(ch=='Y'||ch=='y');

     printf("\nData written successfully");
     fclose(fp);

     printf("\nOUTPUT DATA:\n");
     printf("ROLL NUMBER\tNAME\tMARK");

     fp=fopen("DATA.txt","r");    
     if(fp==NULL){
         printf("\nCan't open file or file doesn't exist");
         exit(0);
     }

     printf("\nData in file:\n");
     while((fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d",&rno,name,&m))!=EOF)
     printf("\n%d%s%d",rno,name,m);    
     getch();
     fclose(fp);
}
```

OUTPUT-
If i enter 2 data for example,then the output is as follows

```
roll number-1
name-abc
mark-24
Do you want to add another data-Y
roll number-2
name-xyz
mark-25
Do you want to add another data-N
Data written successfully
Data in file-
2xyz25
2xyz25
2xyz25
2xyz25
...........
```

until break is given.

Comment: This code is really hard to follow and a large part of that is because it's a singular, sprawling function and the indentation is a wreck. You're going to need to [adopt a formatting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) to avoid this chaos. OTBS is a good place to start.

Comment: `void main()` is not following any standard

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (`for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the format specifiers; `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input and to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow. Such overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding the calls to `fprintf()` suggest placing a space between sets of data so the resulting file is easy to read

Comment: when writing a error message due to a call to a system function, like `fopen()`, the error message should: 1) be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` 2) should include the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest using: `perror()` as that function handles both requirements

Comment: in general, when an error causes a program to exit.  return a value other than 0 because 0 indicates success.  Suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: ` fprintf(fp,"%d %s %d",rno,name,m);`  why output the same data twice to the output file?

Comment: regarding: `while((fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d",&rno,name,&m))!=EOF)`  this will fail when the '%s' format specifier is performed because the resulting file has a VERY long text contents, which will overflow the input buffer 'name' resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the header file: `conio.h` is not portable and the functions it exposes are not portable, so the posted code can only be run under windows

Comment: suggest separating each set/line of data in the output file with a '\n' sequence for ease of readability and to stop two adjacent numbers from being read as a single number

Comment: regarding this in the output: `2xyz25
2xyz25
2xyz25
2xyz25`  This is because the call to `fscanf()` is failing and the code is checking for EOF rather than the proper 3 as a returned value

Comment: Curious, why omit printing the end-of-line character `'\n'` at the end output   with `printf("\n%d%s%d",rno,name,m);`?